# Grab keyboard output

Tags: python, linux, keyboard-events

I want to find a way in Python for detecting "Keyboard event" like [PyUserInput](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyUserInput/0.1.9). I dont want the keyboard to type any character after pressing a button, and ONLY call me event occured.

For example, after pressing the "s" key run the event handler but not typing "S"! this action should be applied in all over the windows not frames such as "Tkinter"

(I want to grab keyboard output signal by python)

Comment: Are you using a window manager or not? If not, lookup curses

Comment: I use pyuserinput, and think it use window manager

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do isn't feasible with python.
What you want to do is essentially make a new driver for your mouse/keyboard.

This is not system independent and there's no good/nice way of doing this with python.

`PyUserInput` attempts to abstract out the system dependency - but this is not complete, and it cannot override the keyboard/mouse completely. What it can do is it can mimic actions on your mouse or keyboard **only if the application allows emulated actions**. A lot of programs like games and a bunch of other software disable emulated actions.

The most stable and significant tool which is not a driver level tool are [autoit](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/)  and [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) - you could try making an autoit/autohotkey script which is executed as a python [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) and use pipes to send and get info from the script.